# Passing object as constructor error

Tags: java, android, object, constructor

In an android game i am writing, i have my code organized as follows:
I have a `World` object, that contains many `Area` objects. Inside each Area object are `Place` objects. These are arranged in multidimensional arrays that make it easy for the player to move around in.
I also have  `Player` and `Inventory` objects that i use as constructors for my `World` object so that ican access the Player/Inventory and make changes to it as necessary (ex: add "item" to inventory; player -10 health).

```
public class World
 Player player;
 Inventory inventory;
public World(Player player, Inventory inventory){
     this.player=player;
     this.inventory=inventory;
}

public Player returnPlayer(){
     return player;
}
public Inventory returnInventory(){
     return inventory;
}
```

to create an Area: i use a World object as a constructor

```
public class StartingArea extends Area
  Player player;
  Inventory inventory;
  World world;
  public StartingArea(World world){
     this.world=world;

     player=world.returnPlayer;
     inventory=world.returnInventory;
}
```

I also have returnPlayer and returnInventory methods within my Area objects.
And when i create my Place objects within my Area objects, i use an Area as a constructor":

```
 House house = new house(this);

public class House extends Place
 Player player;
 Inventory inventory;
 public House(Area area){
   inventory=area.returnInventory;
   player=area.returnPlayer
 }
```

however, by the time i pass down these `player` and `inventory` objects that i created back when i created my `world` object, something gets messed up. I am unable to access the `inventory` object, and my app force closes. I tried making my world instance static:

```
Player player = new Player();
Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
public static World world;
world = new world(player,inventory);
```

and when it is static, i can successfully alter the inventory object
by referring to:

```
MainActivity.world.returnInventory().add(item) //add(Item item) is a method in inventory
```

So, something that I do not quite understand is going on here. Perhaps it is a problem with inheritance (extends)? Or maybe the way i am passing down objects is illegal or improper? I have just started to learn java, so this could be a simple fix or conceptual thing that I missing.

I would like to avoid creating a `static` instance of my `World` object because i am not sure how this will affect supporting multiple save files in my game.

Comment: What is the exception you get in the logcat when your app force closes?

Comment: null object pointer. Forgot to mention: my world object IS static on my main activity due to the ease of sharing it between activities. Could this be why i am getting this error? When i refer to my World object by MainActivity.World, it works, but when i refer to the objects that are passed down by that static World object, i get the null object pointer error

Comment: There is no such exception as 'null object pointer'. Do you mean `NullPointerException`? You can't use an object as a constructor. Do you mean 'factory'?

Comment: I found my problem, checking the logcat helped, thank you for that tip, im going to start paying more attention to that! The problem was my inner object that i used as a constructor parameter was created using "this" outside of the constructor of the previous object, if that makes sense... Anyway, your answer helped! thank you! @EJP

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one player and one inventory you could use singletons to be able to get access to them anywhere. Something like this.

```
public class Player {

    private static Player sPlayer;
    // variables etc

    public static Player getInstance() {
        if (sPlayer == null) {
            sPlayer = new Player();
        }
        return sPlayer;
    }
    // methods etc
}

public class Inventory {

    private static Inventory sInventory;
    // variables etc

    public static Inventory getInstance() {
        if (sInventory == null) {
            sInventory = new Inventory();
        } 
        return sInventory;
    }
    // methods etc
}
```

Then in other activities and classes you could get reference easily without passing them as parameters

```
public class StartingArea extends Area {
    Player player;
    Inventory inventory;
    World world;

    public StartingArea(World world){
        this.world=world;

        player=Player.getInstance();
        inventory=Inventory.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: That would only allow me once instance of a Player object, right? I want to be able to have multiple

Comment: you could still have multiple objects for example if you call Player player2 = new player(); or create another object that extends a player for example class Enemy extends Player. Theres nothing stopping you having multiple player objects, just one singleton instance